# How to only print first two words of a certain column with awk

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file `A.tsv` (field separator : `\t`) :

```
BC02    Streptococcus oralis  chromosome, complete genome   2712    94  0   99.073  2053209 CP023507.1  1597
BC02    Staphylococcus aureus  chromosome, complete genome  2712    94  0   99.073  2053209 CP023507.1  1597
BC02    Streptococcus sp.  chromosome, complete genome  2712    94  0   99.073  2053209 CP023507.1  1597
```

And I want to add a new column at the end of each line with only the first two words of the column `$2`, in order to get:

```
BC02    Streptococcus oralis  chromosome, complete genome   2712    94  0   99.073  2053209 CP023507.1  1597    Streptococcus oralis
BC02    Staphylococcus aureus  chromosome, complete genome  2712    94  0   99.073  2053209 CP023507.1  1597    Staphylococcus aureus
BC02    Streptococcus sp.  chromosome, complete genome  2712    94  0   99.073  2053209 CP023507.1  1597    Streptococcus sp.
```

I try to look at some awk command using this [stack subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46895013/print-1st-word-of-1st-column-and-2nd-word-of-2nd-column-in-a-single-line) but nothing similar enough to have a start.

Do you know how to do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to [split()](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) the second column on spaces and print how many words do you want, like

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="\t" }
{ split($2, tmp, " "); print $0, tmp[1], tmp[2] }' infile
```

Comment: Thanks ! I will remember using split next time

Answer (score 0):

For more complex `tsv`, e.g. if you had tabs inside fields, `awk` won't work well. Then, you should use a proper CSV parser, e.g. `python`'s `csv` module:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import csv
with open('A.tsv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
        row.append(' '.join(row[1].split()[:2]))
        print('\t'.join(row))
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for `gensub()` and `\s/\S` shorthand:

```
$ awk '{print gensub(/\S+\s+(\S+\s+\S+).*/,"&\t\\1",1)}' file
BC02    Streptococcus oralis  chromosome, complete genome   2712    94  0   99.073  2053209 CP023507.1  1597    Streptococcus oralis
BC02    Staphylococcus aureus  chromosome, complete genome  2712    94  0   99.073  2053209 CP023507.1  1597    Staphylococcus aureus
BC02    Streptococcus sp.  chromosome, complete genome  2712    94  0   99.073  2053209 CP023507.1  1597        Streptococcus sp.
```

or a bit briefer with GNU sed:

```
$ sed -E 's/\S+\s+(\S+\s+\S+).*/&\t\1/' file
BC02    Streptococcus oralis  chromosome, complete genome   2712    94  0   99.073  2053209 CP023507.1  1597    Streptococcus oralis
BC02    Staphylococcus aureus  chromosome, complete genome  2712    94  0   99.073  2053209 CP023507.1  1597    Staphylococcus aureus
BC02    Streptococcus sp.  chromosome, complete genome  2712    94  0   99.073  2053209 CP023507.1  1597        Streptococcus sp.
```

The above assumes the first field doesn't contain any white space, as shown in your examples.

Answer (score 0):

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)**

```
raku -ne 'print $_, "\t"; .split(/\t/).[1].words.[0..1].put;'
```

Sample Input:

```
BC02    Streptococcus oralis  chromosome, complete genome   2712    94  0   99.073  2053209 CP023507.1  1597
BC02    Staphylococcus aureus  chromosome, complete genome  2712    94  0   99.073  2053209 CP023507.1  1597
BC02    Streptococcus sp.  chromosome, complete genome  2712    94  0   99.073  2053209 CP023507.1  1597
```

Breaking the code above into three (3) parts,

1). split on tabs, pull out the second element (remembering that in Raku numbering starts from zero):

```
raku -ne '.split(/\t/).[1].put;'
```

gives Sample Output:

```
Streptococcus oralis  chromosome, complete genome
Staphylococcus aureus  chromosome, complete genome
Streptococcus sp.  chromosome, complete genome
```

2). Break into whitespace-separated `words`, take the first two (2):

```
raku -ne '.split(/\t/).[1].words.[0..1].put;'
```

gives Sample Output:

```
Streptococcus oralis
Staphylococcus aureus
Streptococcus sp.
```

3). Combine above with the entire pre-existing line, by printing the Raku `$_` topic variable first (followed by a `\t`):

```
raku -ne 'print $_, "\t"; .split(/\t/).[1].words.[0..1].put;'
```

gives Sample Output:

```
BC02    Streptococcus oralis  chromosome, complete genome   2712    94  0   99.073  2053209 CP023507.1  1597    Streptococcus oralis
BC02    Staphylococcus aureus  chromosome, complete genome  2712    94  0   99.073  2053209 CP023507.1  1597    Staphylococcus aureus
BC02    Streptococcus sp.  chromosome, complete genome  2712    94  0   99.073  2053209 CP023507.1  1597    Streptococcus sp.
```

https://raku.org/